# How to update live tile with BackgroundDownloader?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, background-task

I'd like to show downloading status in live tile. I know I can update live tiles from background tasks. But how does it work with background downloader ? Can I update live tile from Progress ? I guess no because this callback works in main app instead of background task.

Comment: Add some communication between the main app and background task.

Comment: @crea7or, how ? Tile should be updated when the main app is closed.

Comment: Did you tested [BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsForTransferGroupAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.getcurrentdownloadsfortransfergroupasync.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from background agent?

Comment: @crea7or, no. But I haven't seen examples of such use this method. Have you tried ?

Comment: Nope, just gues. Here is [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/backgroundtransfer/cs/backgroundtransfer/scenario3_notifications.xaml.cs).